# i want to create a 2D array which consist of nodes name and its x y coordinate using numpy python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to create an 2D array for an input asking no of nodes and for each node accepting 2 value x coordinate and y coordinate from user and generating its 2D array where consist 3 column node, x coordinate, y coordinate.

**Input:**

```
enter the number of nodes:3
10 12
12 13
5 6
```

**output**

```
[A 10 12
 B 12 13
 C 5 6 ]
```

Comment: A list of 3 element lists with these 3 values is a better structure.

Answer (score 0):

Define 2 functions:

```
def foo(node):
    return [node]+[int(i) for i in input('for node: %s: '%node).split()]

def foobar():
    n = input('enter the number of nodes:')
    n = int(n)
    alist=[]
    for i,n in zip(range(n),'ABCDEF'):
        alist.append(foo(n))
    return alist
```

And get a list of lists, each based on your input:

```
In [348]: foobar()
enter the number of nodes:3
for node: A: 10 12
for node: B: 12 13
for node: C: 5 6
Out[348]: [['A', 10, 12], ['B', 12, 13], ['C', 5, 6]]
```

A mix of node name strings and numbers does not make a good numpy array.

It could be turned into an array of strings.  Or an `object` dtype array.  Or a structured array.  Or better yet, one array of node names, and another 2d with just 2 columns, the coordinates.